# Derivative of a linear function

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations, tangent-line, slope

I have to find the coefficients for m and n in the following linear function
$() =  + $
the tangent goes through the points $(1,-3)$
then $(1) =  +  = −3$
and then this comes up $′() = 4 − 3$
I understand that this is a derivative, but I don't remember any formula where this $(4x)$ comes from
so my question is what is this $4x$?
The quadratic function is f(x) = 2x ² -3x - 2

Comment: Where $f'(x)$ comes from?

Comment: Surely you have left off the definition of $f(x)$, no?

Comment: Yes, just realize this is the derivative for the quadratic function not the linear function and that is why I didn’t understand

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^n = n x^{n-1}$$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(2x^2-3x-2)= 2(2x)-3=4x-3$$

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was I really didn’t understand the ration between the two functions and got confused, but I get it know, thank you.

Comment: i have another question concerning the same problem.

Comment: In this question i am to find the equation and the slope of the tangent given the quadratic function and a linear function tangent to the quadratic, and there is one thing i didn't understand in the resolution: (1) =  +  = −3
′() = 4 − 3
′(1) = 4 − 3 = 1 ⟹  = 1. I know that  the derivative of the quadratic will have the same slope as the linear function tangent to it , but i don't understand why  = 1, is it because they equated the linear function and the quadratic derivative and then equated the coefficients?  g(x) mx + n = f'(x) 4 − 3

Comment: Yes exactly that, you must use the 'initial' values to find the values of the gradient of the slope.